# Dictionaries within a list

Tags: python, dictionary

suppose I have the following list of dictionaries:

```
database = [{'Job title': 'painter', 'Email address': 'xxx@yyy.com', 'Last name': 'Wright', 'First name': 'James', 'Company': 'Swift'},
{'Job title': 'plumber', 'Email address': 'xxx@yyy.com', 'Last name': 'Bright', 'First name': 'James', 'Company': 'ABD Plumbing'},
{'Job title': 'brick layer', 'Email address': 'xxx@yyy.com', 'Last name': 'Smith', 'First name': 'John', 'Company': 'Bricky brick'}]
```

I'm entering the following code so I can print information about a person given their first name (I will be changing this, to search for last name, company, job title etc, using a variable):

```
print(next(item for item in database if item['First name'] == 'James'))
```

The issue arises as I have two First name's which are equal, namely James. How do I adjust the code so that it prints out information about all the James's in the database?

Comment: `[item for item in database if item['First name'] == 'James']`

Comment: remove the next()...

Comment: vaultah's answer is cool enough, here is the other one!     filter(lambda x:x['First name'] == 'James', database)     , python would just handle the iterator/vector for you, a 'for' is enough for most situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the next().

```
print([item for item in database if item['First name'] == 'James'])
```